# Why do single quote( ' ) and double quote( " ) get different results in python's json module?

Tags: python, json

I have such piece of python code:

```
import json
single_quote = '{"key": "value"}'
double_quote = "{'key': 'value'}"
data = json.loads(single_quote) # get a dict: {'key': 'value'}
data = json.loads(double_quote) # get a ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

In python, `single_quote` and `double_quote` make no technical differences, don't they? Then why `single_quote` works and `double_quote` doesn't?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because only the first example is valid JSON. JSON data have keys and values surrounded by `"..."` and not `'...'`.

There are other "rules" that you may not be expecting. There's a great list on this wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example). For example, booleans should be lowercase (`true` and `false`) and not `True` and `False`. JSON != Python.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the outside quotes that matter, it's the *literal* quotes in the JSON string (must be `"`)

ie. This is ok (but cumbersome)

```
double_quote = "{\"key\": \"value\"}"
```

You can also use triple quotes

```
'''{"key": "value"}'''
"""{"key": "value"}"""
```

The choices of quotes are there so you hardly ever need to use the ugly/cumbersome versions

Answer (score 1):

`JSON` is a language-free format for exchanging data. Although `single_quote` and `double_quote` make no difference in `Python`, they're different in `JSON` cause a `JSON` object will be processed by other languages as well.